# Balanced parentheses parser Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a balanced parentheses parser by using recursion and produce a tree.

For example, if you pass in `'()()'` the tree would be constructed like this

step 1

```
  B
  |
empty
```

step 2

```
       B 
   /   |   \   \
  (  empty  )   B
                |
              empty
```

step 3

```
      B 
  /   |   \    \
 (  empty  )    B
             /  |  \   \
            ( empty )   B
                        |
                      empty
```

Right now, my code "kind of" work for a legit input like '()()', but it is supposed to give me False for something like '())('. It is not returning False. Can I get help with this?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label
        self.leftmostChild = None
        self.rightSibling = None


def makeNode0(x):
    root = Node(None)
    root.label = x

    return root


def makeNode1(x, t):
    root = makeNode0(x)
    root.leftmostChild = t

    return root


def makeNode4(x, t1, t2, t3, t4):
    root = makeNode1(x, t1)
    t1.rightSibling = t2
    t2.rightSibling = t3
    t3.rightSibling = t4

    return root


nextTerminal = "())("


def B(index):
    firstB = Node(None)
    secondB = Node(None)

    if index != len(nextTerminal):
        if nextTerminal[index] == '(':
            index += 1
            firstB = B(index)

            if firstB is not False and nextTerminal[index] == ')':
                index += 1
                secondB = B(index)

                if secondB is False:
                    return False
                else:
                    return makeNode4('B', makeNode0('('), firstB, makeNode0(')'), secondB)
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return makeNode1('B', makeNode0('emp'))


b = B(0)
```

Comment: Would you like a better algorithm, or would you like help identifying bugs in your code? There is a much simpler way to do this.

Comment: Oh I just need to find out why my code doesn't work. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: You could use `eval` and catch any `SyntaxError`

Comment: I don't have syntax errors

Comment: @PTN your code indeed looks way too complicated. First of all, I'd not return False for broken trees, rather raise an exception right away. If you want to return false anyway, then wrap this into another function.

Comment: Your diagrams show nodes that each have a label and _four_ children (or three and a sibling --- the total is still four), but your `Node` class has only two children: `leftmostChild` and `rightSibling`.  I don't see how your code could possibly produce those data structures --- `Node` should produce only binary trees.  Are you (ab)using `Node` to create linked lists of multiple children?  The name "sibling" suggests that's your intent, but your diagrams don't show it.

Comment: Your parse trees look ... unusual. I'd expect a top level node with at most three children (`B`, `B`, `emp`) (with the final `emp` optional), where both `B`s would again again have `(`, `emp`, `)`. But note that a simpler approach is to recurse *down* on `(` and to recurse *up* on `)`. The sequence is wrong when you have still tokens left when back at the top level or when running out of tokens.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to outline a second approach here, in the hopes that it provides you with some insight into why your current program isn't working. To be frank, I'm not certain what's going on - I initially thought that each right sibling indicated an additional parenthetical statement, but it seems like the tree's structure is hardcoded, regardless of the parentheses. My suggestion would be to start from the below solution and work your way towards creating these trees.

1. Keep track of a variable `depth`.
2. For every start parenthesis, increment `depth` by 1.
3. For every end parenthesis, decrement `depth` by 1. If `depth` is negative, we have encountered an end parenthesis too soon -- return `false`.

After processing all parentheses, check that `depth` is 0. Otherwise, we had too many start parentheses.

Comment: He's not looking for a second approach. He wants to know what's wrong with his code - it's a learning experience.

Comment: That's fair. I thought that maybe working from the new approach to his original one would help. Not entirely sure what the code is doing but wanted to help somehow, without providing faulty advice.